# Finding the intersection of a circle and an ellipse

Tags: geometry, intersection, points, ellipse

I need to find the intersection points of a circle with an ellipse, where

[image: Ellipse]

is a general ellipse centred on *(x0, y0)* with semi-major axis *a* and semi-minor axis *b*, and

[image: Circle]

is a circle of radius r, centred on *(x1, y1)*

Any assistance is much appreciated

Comment: https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfEllipses.pdf

Comment: That is not general ellipse but axis aligned one instead (general/arbitrary ellipse has also `x*y` therms and or sin,cos rotation formula) ...  What sort of solution you need algebraic/numeric/iterative? what precision ? where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: Hi, I need to find a general algebraic solution for finding the points where the circle intersects the ellipse. The solution for an axis-aligned ellipse would be great for a starter. The solution can be iterative as it will ultimately be coded in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Found some C# code which I've adapted and converted to java to suit my purposes

[Where two ellipses intersect](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/11/see-where-two-ellipses-intersect-in-c-part-1/)

Just treat the circle as a special case of an ellipse where axes *a* and *b* are equal